# Tabulation for multiple line string PHP

Tags: php

Let's say you have a php string that has multiple html lines, for example:

```
$string = "<p>
   Vestibulum ac diam sit amet
</p>
<p>
   Vestibulum ac diam sit amet
</p>
<p>
   Vestibulum ac diam sit amet
</p>";
```

And I'm displaying it this way:

```
        <div>
            <div>
                <?php echo $string . PHP_EOL; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I get the paragraphs to have the same tabulation as the opening php tag? I know I can add tabs in the $string, but if I'm using this string in multiple places, I may not want the same tabulation for each place.

What I get is this:

```
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>
    Vestibulum ac diam sit amet
</p>
<p>
    Vestibulum ac diam sit amet
</p>
<p>
    Vestibulum ac diam sit amet
</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What I want is this:

```
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        Vestibulum ac diam sit amet
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Vestibulum ac diam sit amet
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Vestibulum ac diam sit amet
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Tabs in HTML isn't really something you should care about.

Comment: So you want your html code to become bigger hence slower to load just because it looks better in case someone watches the html without auto formatting?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference. Nobody is going to dig up the html source and comment on its beauty.

Comment: Irrelevant comments. There's lots of sillier questions around. I like my html well formatted as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML indentation doesn't really matter and, as people said in the comments, makes the code unnecessarily bigger. However, if you really want to indent it, you can use this function:

```
function indent_html($code, $num)
{
    $tabs = str_repeat("\t", $num); // or spaces if you want
    return $tabs.str_replace("\n", "\n$tabs", $code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like:

```
tidy_get_output();
```

[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tidy-get-output.php)